# Problem parsing XML document with namespaces using Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Using Python lxml library, I'm trying to parse a XML document as follows:

```
<ns:searchByScientificNameResponse xmlns:ns="http://itis_service.itis.usgs.gov">
<ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://data.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd" xmlns:ax23="http://metadata.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd" xmlns:ax26="http://itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:SvcScientificNameList">
<ax21:scientificNames xsi:type="ax21:SvcScientificName">
<ax21:tsn>26339</ax21:tsn>
<ax21:author>L.</ax21:author>
<ax21:combinedName>Vicia faba</ax21:combinedName>
<ax21:kingdom>Plantae</ax21:kingdom>
<ax21:unitInd1 xsi:nil="true" />
<ax21:unitInd2 xsi:nil="true" />
<ax21:unitInd3 xsi:nil="true" />
<ax21:unitInd4 xsi:nil="true" />
<ax21:unitName1>Vicia</ax21:unitName1>
<ax21:unitName2>faba</ax21:unitName2>
<ax21:unitName3 xsi:nil="true" />
<ax21:unitName4 xsi:nil="true" />
</ax21:scientificNames>
</ns:return>
</ns:searchByScientificNameResponse>
```

Specifically, I want to get the value of the "ax21:tsn" element (in this case, the integer 26339).

I tried the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002635/parsing-multiple-namespaces-xml-in-python-using-lxml), without success. Here is my code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
#print(ET.tostring(tree))

namespaces = {'ax21': 'http://data.itis_service.itis.usgs.gov/xsd'} 
tsn = tree.find('scientificNames/tsn', namespaces)
print(tsn)
```

It just returns nothing. It there a really intelligent way of doing this using xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `scientificNames` is not a direct child of the root element; it is a grandchild.
2. You need to use the `ax21` prefix in the XPath expression.

The following works:

```
tsn = tree.find('.//ax21:scientificNames/ax21:tsn', namespaces)
```

Or simply:

```
tsn = tree.find('.//ax21:tsn', namespaces)
```

Comment: But it seems it does not work for "findall()".

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Note that `findall` returns a list while `find` returns a single element.

Comment: This returns an empty list: common_names = tree.findall(".//ax21:commonNames:ax21:commonName", namespaces)

Comment: Please post a new question.